# How to adjust xrange to min and max of the points actually plotted in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

Normally the xrange and yrange are adjusted to fit the largest and smallest value in the datafile, when plotting according to

```
plot "my_file.dat" u 1:2
```

Suppose I want to apply a cutoff to the y-values, so that I only include the points whose y-value is larger than, say 1. If I do

```
plot "my_file.dat" u 1:($2>1?$2:NaN)
```

I indeed select only those points. The problem, however, is that the xrange is still adjusted to the range of column 1 of the *entire* datafile, rather than to only those points which are actually plotted. How can I fix this? My gnuplot version is 5.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also have to *filter* the undesired x-values in a similar way:

```
plot 'my_file.dat' u ($2 > 1 ? $1 : NaN):($2 > 1 ? $2: NaN)
```

If you want to draw a line between these points, a different way of filtering is necessary: see [Plotting lines with missing datapoints for multidimensional data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65341190/plotting-lines-with-missing-datapoints-for-multidimensional-data)

Comment: Thanks for the help, and also for the link!